# A device named "iPhone" in Location Services on my iPad will not stay deleted

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-device-management

iPad/General/Restrictions/Location Services is on.
Share my location is on.
From this device - MyiPad (I named my ipad MyiPad)
Then under that it shows the word iPhone. 
My iPhone is named lAiPhone not iPhone.

I am able to swipe it to the left and select delete, but then is is back in about 3 seconds.

I want to know exactly what it is. What can I check. How can i get rid of it. I do not have any paired devices.

Comment: Any iPhones logged into iCloud with the same appleId?

Comment: Yes my iphone, but I named my iPhone.

Comment: if it was my iphone i would think it would be listed as a device seperate and show the correct name that i named it. Hmm ...I will try and log out and then back in. Thank you